# Gradle Groovy property logical results appear wrong?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have this debug code in `root/build.gradle`:

```
task copyJenkinsIdea(type: Copy) {
    onlyIf {
        project.hasProperty("isJenkins")
    }
    doLast {
        println "Do Jenkins-specific setup" 
        println "${project.hasProperty("isJenkins")} && ${isJenkins} = ${(project.hasProperty("isJenkins") && isJenkins)}"
        println "${project.hasProperty("isJenkins")} && ${project.isJenkins} = ${(project.hasProperty("isJenkins") && project.isJenkins)}"
        println "true && false = ${(true && false)}"
    }
        from ".idea/Jenkins"
        into ".idea"
    
}
```

I run it with this command:

```
./gradlew --console=verbose -PisJenkins=false assembleDebug
```

Task dependency in `root/app/build.gradle`

```
preBuild.dependsOn(":copyJenkinsIdea")
```

And it gives me this output:

```
> Configure project :app
[snip]

> Task :copyJenkinsIdea
Do Jenkins-specific setup
true && false = true
true && false = true
true && false = false
```

The property is not present in the gradle.properties file.

I've got to be missing something, because this is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, Groovy can't know that the property being passed in is a boolean.
It's doing

```
class java.lang.Boolean && class java.lang.String
true && "false"
```

Which is, in fact, `true`.